# Integral of $\frac{5z^2 - 8}{z^3-2z^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I calculated the integral of $\frac{5z^2 - 8}{z^3-2z^2}$ along the path of unit circle of centre 0. I used partial fractions and obtained $2\int\limits^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{i e^{it}} {e^{it}} dt + 3\int\limits^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{i e^{it}} {e^{it}-2} dt + 4\int\limits^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{i e^{it}} {(e^{it})^2} dt$. The two last terms are zero and the first is $2\pi i$, so the final result is $4\pi i$. But now I am asked which path could be chosen instead of the unit circle to make the inteegral $-2\pi i$. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $z^3-2z^2=0$ iff $z=0$ or $z=2$.  A complex integral along a closed path does not depend on the given path, but on the poles that the path enclose.
Also remember that the path can't contain $z=0$ or $z=2$, otherwise the integral won't be defined. Since you have two poles $z=0$ and $z=2$ there are several options:

- If the path enclose $z=0$ but no $z=2$ you have already show that the integral has value $4\pi i$.
- If the path does not enclose $z=0$ nor $z=2$ then the integral is trivially $0$.

And there are two cases left:

- If the path enclose $z=2$ but no $z=0$.
- If the path enclose $z=0$ and $z=2$.

So the solution to your problem is one of those two cases, I'll let you check which is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you for your help!